# Why is the Virchow node involved in Gastric Adeonocarcinoma?

Tags: cancer, surgery, stomach, anatomy, metastatic-cancer

The lymph node drainage of the stomach is via the pyloric and related lymph nodes. Either way, the supraclavicular node (Virchow's node) is not the first lymph node that drains the Stomach. According to Robbins and Cortran: Pathologic Basis of Disease, the Virchow node is a common site of metastasis. I checked Bailey's surgery textbook as well, and they did explain the other tumors- Krukenberg and Sister-Mary-Joseph nodules- as being due to the serosal infiltration of the original adenocarcinoma. This, however doesn't explain the supraclavicular lymph node involvement. Can anybody give me a reason for this?

Comment: I know this is a disheartening comment, but I googled your question almost verbatim and the first hit explained the anatomy leading to that sentinel node's involvement in GI and other malignancies. Did you do this? What happened when you did? I understand that Google algorithms vary, so not everyone will have the same outcome.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?